# I want to delete "words" from cells in Excel but keep alphanumeric text

Tags: excel, alphanumeric

I have some cells in a particular column with alphanumeric text along with other words or numbers.

examples for cells are in **bold**:

**BOTTOM: J103 NOTE 13**

I want to delete BOTTOM:, NOTE and 13 but keep J103

The text for J103 may contain more than one letter and a range of one to four numbers, but they will always be combined and start with the same letters for a particular row. Some cells will only have text I want to keep but will be separated by commas. Cells that meet this criteria shall be ignored, shown below.

**CR33, CR45, CR49**    -  Row 1

**D12, D13, D14, D104** -  Row 2

Words I want deleted will never have numbers. Stand alone numbers won't have letters and if by some odd occurrence they do, it will be 13a where the letters are last.

If a particular cell has:

**TOP: J104 Bottom: J103**

I would like both TOP: and BOTTOM: removed and the remaining J104 and J103 comma delimited.

**J104, J103**

I would prefer this all as a macro if possible.

I am a beginner in VBA so be gentle

It was suggested by Andy G to use Regular Expressions with his code in his reply.

I have read up on the matter but I don't fully understand what is actually taking place. This is what I tried to no avail.

```
Sub test()
Dim rngToSearch As Range
Dim rng As Range
'Tools References - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Dim rgx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches As Variant, match As Variant
Dim strTemp As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cellText As String
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

rgx.Pattern = "[A-Z]+\d{1,4}"
'rgx.IgnoreCase = True
rgx.Global = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rngToSearch = Range("D1:D" & LastRow).CurrentRegion
    For Each rng In rngToSearch
    strTemp = ""
    Set matches = rgx.Execute(rng.Value)
    For Each match In matches
        strTemp = strTemp & match.Value & ","
    Next match
    If Len(strTemp) > 0 Then
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
    End If
Next rng
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I appreciate any answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Office 2007.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to do this: http://www.tmehta.com/regexp/

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the code below, but you'll need to study it in order to understand and apply it.

```
Sub KeepCodes()
    Dim rngToSearch As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    'Tools References - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim rgx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim matches As Variant, match As Variant
    Dim strTemp As String

    rgx.Pattern = "[A-Z]+\d{1,4}"
    'rgx.IgnoreCase = True
    rgx.Global = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rngToSearch = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For Each rng In rngToSearch
        strTemp = ""
        Set matches = rgx.Execute(rng.Value)
        For Each match In matches
            strTemp = strTemp & match.Value & ","
        Next match
        If Len(strTemp) > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Read this [MSDN regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic3) article.

Comment: Any way to get it to do just a selected cell? I do have code already to run through the rows of a column to the last row.

I assume it's in the rgx.Global = True line.

Comment: If you study the code (and the regex link I provided) you will be able to modify it. And, no, it is not related to `rgx.Global`.

Comment: I've studied the code and tried few things but I can't manage to get just a single column to perform the task, the whole sheet gets changed. What do I need to change so ONLY a specific column is affected?